# Sorting in rails app

Tags: ruby

I created an app that gives points to students. I want to sort the points in descending order. This is my code.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li> <%= user.points%></li>
<%end%>
```

This code outputs the points from each student, but when I try to add `sort!` after `user.points`, it gives me an error. I am not sure where I should do this.

Comment: What is `points`? Is it a number (i.e. you want to sort users depending on their points) or is it a collection of objects (a Point model for example)?

Comment: Have you tried: `<% @users.sort.each do |user| %>` ? Also, another way would be to use a helper method to sort however way you want it sorted, create a separate variable in your controller to store this sorted element, and use that variable in your view like you have above but instead `<% @sorted_users.each do |user| %>`

Comment: what error did it shows? Is points is a model or it is just a column of user model?

Comment: Can you post some details on this? like the controller, and error you getting?

Comment: If points is a column in user's table, you can do this in your controller `@users = User.order('points desc')`

Comment: sorry I  didn't give enough info . I thought i gave enough to answer my simple question. My question has been answered , though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @users.sort_by{|u| u.points}.reverse.each do |user| %>
  <li> <%= user.points%></li>
<% end %>
```

**Note:** I have used `reverese` as you have mentioned `I want to sort the points in descending order.` But It's always good practise to assign data to object  in controller as per your requirement.

Do it in controller like:

```
@users = User.order(points: :desc) # this will fetch users in descending order on basis of points
```

then in view simply use:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li> <%= user.points%></li>
<%end%>
```

for more info regarding **[Order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order)**

Comment: thanks alot! this helped. it was exactly what i needed!

Comment: @VictorLara : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go for:

```
<% @users.sort_by{|u| u.points}.each do |user| %>
<li> <%= user.points%></li>
<%end%>
```

Or you can go for:

```
@users=User.order(:points)
```

Comment: this gave me this : #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd4a54513a8>

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Active Record .order is what you need.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

For example:

```
  User.order(:points)
```

would provide you with users ordered by points. Do the ordering from your controller rather in your view.